# Cognito, Angular2, and Java/Spring

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, angular, amazon-cognito

We are in the process of building a new web application and have decided our technology stack will use many AWS services, Java-Spring, and Angular2. We plan to also build iOS and Android apps in the future so I love the features that Cognito provides. However, I can't seem to find any good documentation/examples of Angular2/Java applications using Cognito. The sample apps seem to be strictly front-end or backend. How do I authenticate via Cognito in Angular2, while also checking Cognito user permissions in the back-end Java/Spring app? I need to authenticate my restful endpoints against the user logged in from Angular.

Comment: Cognito will give you three JWT tokens (Id, access and refresh), if you set up your API gateway with a user pool authenticator it can do the authentication for you along with granting access (it takes the id token) depending on which role/policies you've attached to the user.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly you are suggesting that I do all my my authentication on the backend then? I read a post somewhere else that suggested that might not be the best idea as you lose a lot of built-in functionality from the Javascript library. I would absolutely love to find a sample program doing what I am trying to do.

Comment: The front-end is not and cannot be trusted, any authentication done there is just for convenience and has to be done again in the back-end. You use the the Cognito API for receiving a JWT token from the back-end which you then supply in your requests as the "authentication" header (authentication is done in the back-end here). An easy authentication (not very fine grained) you can do is with the user pool authenticator for Api gateway. You do not lose any functionality from the javascript library as you can use your token for authentication.

Comment: You should also consider if you want your front-end aws agnostic or not, there are pros and cons of both.

Comment: I really wanted to try this setup because my user pool had SAML federation. So it was hard for me to identify and redirect the user from the backend. Getting the user authenticated in the client with all possible redirects and using the token in the backend to verify was simple. Well, was there any solution @Gremash ?